# Graphql generic mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I have a set of graphql types that are similar enough that can be edited generically. I have written the code to display them and mutate on the client side yet now am having problems with writing the mutation query that would work. Current implementation:

```
 let node1 = {
                 id: 1,
                 type: 'theme',
                 fields: {name: 'potatoes'}       
             };

 let node2 = {
                 id: 1,
                 type: 'subject',
                 fields: {
                             short_name: 'cool potatoes',
                             long_name: 'cool potatoes that grow on the mountain'
                         }       
             };

....

 save: function (node) {
    this.$apollo.mutate({
      // Query
      mutation: gql`mutation ($id: Int!) {
      update_data_${node.type}(where: {id: {_eq: $id}}, _set: ${node.fields}) {
        affected_rows
      }
  }`,
      variables: {
        id: node.id
      }
    })
  }
```

Not also it does not work now (because it does not want to interpolate the fields properly) but also I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work by:

```
_set: ${JSON.stringify(node.fields).replace(/"(w+)"s*:/g, '$1:')}
```

Looks horrid but works. I hope there is a more "graphql" way to do this.